# How can I get the application's icon from the package name?

Tags: android

I have tried various solution from stack overflow with no luck. What I want.

1. I know package name of different applications.
2. I want to get application Icon from those package name.
3. Show those icons in Image View.

For example, I have a package name `com.example.testnotification`. How to get this apps icon and show it in an ImageView?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Try this:

```
try
{
    Drawable icon = getContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.example.testnotification");
    imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to get the icon (picture) of any installed application from its package name, then just copy and paste this code. It will work:

```
try
{
    Drawable d = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.AdhamiPiranJhandukhel.com");
    my_imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This also works:

```
try
{
    Drawable d = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(getApplicationInfo());
    my_imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the above answers, but was only getting icons from system apps, issue faced in Android 11 (API level 30) or higher, a little digging led me to [this docs page](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) which said that you need to add the following permission in your AndroidManifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
```

And now all icons are visible.

I used the following piece of code to implement the said functionality using DataBinding:

```
@BindingAdapter("getImageFromPackageName")
fun ImageView.getImageFromPackageName(packageName: String) {
    try {
        val icon = context.packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageName)
        this.setImageDrawable(icon)
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Hope that helps, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
    Drawable drawable = getPackageManager()
            .getApplicationIcon("com.whatsapp");
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```