# Retrieve and Display Installed Android Apps

Tags: android, listview

I want to create an android code that can retrieve all installed apps in my device and display them with icons in a good format.  How do I display the list of apps installed in the system with a good layout?

Comment: What did you try so far? Where exactly do you encounter issues with your implementation?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? This is extremely easy and is covered in almost any examples of PackageManager anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You might need to learn about `ListView`:
   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html
2. To get a list of all installed apps, you can follow this link: [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)
3. Try putting the list of all apps in your `ListView`
4. To get app icon, after you get the list of all apps, you will also get their package names - follow this link:
   [How can I get the application's icon from the package name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985500/how-can-i-get-the-applications-icon-from-the-package-name)

Answer (score 0):

Use `PackageManager` to get all details of installed `packages`

```
 PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
 List apps = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```