# Get icon of the package that is recently installed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-package-managers

I am receiving the name and other details of the package that is recently added by implementing `onReceive()` of  `broadcastreceiver` , but i have no idea how to get icon of that package. 
I am unable to get `packageManager()` in `brodcast Receiver`

**Is that possible to get icon from intent ??**

```
public class PackageActionsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = PackageActionsReceiver.class
        .getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (UtilSharedPreference.isRegistered(context)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceiver");
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        Package packageBean = new Package();
        Drawable tempDrawableImage;
        packageBean.setPackageName(data.getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart());
        if (intent.getAction().equals(
                Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED.toString())) {
            packageBean.setInfo("I");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)) {
            packageBean.setInfo("U");
        } else if (intent.getAction()
                .equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED)) {
            packageBean.setInfo("R");
        }
        packageBean.setName(Utils.getApplicationName(context, intent
                .getData().getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart(),
                PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES));
        packageBean.setDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

        PackageDataSource packageSource = new PackageDataSource(context);
        packageSource.open();
        packageSource.addNewPackage(packageBean);
        packageSource.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get the application's icon from the package name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985500/how-can-i-get-the-applications-icon-from-the-package-name)

Comment: how can i use packageManager() in broacastReceiver???

Comment: Hardik please upload your code..!!

Comment: pass the context and use it like context.packageManager()

Comment: @HardikPatel check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the packageManager from context that you have on the onReceive Method

e.g.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
context.getPackageManager()
}
```

and you can use this answer

```
Drawable icon = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.example.testnotification");
imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985500/how-can-i-get-the-applications-icon-from-the-package-name)

Comment: Thnx @sandy , it helped me.... i have applied logic this way,
`DrawableImage = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(data.getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart());`

as i need to get icon of application received by brodcast receiver.

Comment: @HardikPatel if you find my answer is helpful to your question please accept answer so others can get help from here thanks :)