# how to extract a png file for the icon of the last installed app

Tags: java, android, bitmap, broadcastreceiver, imageicon

I was wondering if it is possible to get the icon (in png form) from the last installed app that I download on my phone?

I am writing an app that I can put on my phone, which will extract the last installed app's package name, common name, and icon (in png form). I got the package name and common name, but now I am trying to get the icon file. Here is the code I have so far from reading around on the web for how to do this, but I seem to be missing something. All of my code for extracting the icon is in the "try" statement.

```
public class NewInstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("NewInstallReceiver", "Intent: " + intent.getAction());


    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo ai;
    try {
        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart(), 0);
        Log.d("PACKAGE NAME","Intent" + ai);
    } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        ai = null;
    }
    final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
    Log.d("Application NAME", "Intent: " + applicationName);




    // http://www.carbonrider.com/2016/01/01/extract-app-icon-in-android/

    try {
        Drawable icon = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(ai);
        Log.d("ICON BITMAPDRAWABLE", "Intent: " + icon);

        BitmapDrawable bitmapIcon = (BitmapDrawable)icon;
        Log.d("ICON 11111", "Intent: " + bitmapIcon);

        FileOutputStream fosIcon = context.openFileOutput(ai + ".png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Log.d("ICON 22222", "Intent: " + fosIcon);

        bitmapIcon.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fosIcon);
        InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput(ai + ".png");
        Log.d("ICON NAME 33333", "Intent: " + inputStream);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        Log.d("ICON bitmap 44444", "Intent: " + bitmap);

        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
        Log.d("ICON drawable 55555", "Intent: " + drawable);

        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }


    catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("CATCH", "CATCH ");
    }


}



}
```

Comment: What about it seems to not be working?

Comment: Hello @DeeV The problem I am having is that I can not seem to locate where .png is getting created? I search my whole directory and it doesn't seem like the file that I am creating (applicationName.png) exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get the application's icon from the package name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985500/how-can-i-get-the-applications-icon-from-the-package-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file directory that `Context#openFilesInput()` opens is the same private directory that `Context#getFilesDir()` returns. You won't be able to open this folder through ADB unless your phone is rooted.  You can retrieve the `File` object by doing this though:

`File imageFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "imgName.png");`

It's important to note, that currently you're naming the image after whatever `ApplicationInfo#toString()` returns.  You may want to open the file with the `applicationName + ".png` instead. Or since this is the latest installed app, you save it as "latestApp.png" or something unique.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I was looking for!